# intelliJ JUnit not visible as Testing Library

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit

I added Junit manually to [libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAKw3.jpg). Therefore it was also automatically added to [module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/La9oK.jpg). When I click ["create test"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U35Ve.jpg). Then JUnit is [not visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzJha.jpg).

what to do to make junit visible?

Comment: Is the class for which you're trying to create the test written in Groovy?

Comment: No, this class called KNN is written in java.

Comment: Try removing the groovy-all jar from the dependencies of your module?

Comment: I tried, the problem still exists.

Answer (score 2):

This might be caused by the disabled `JUnit` plugin. Go to `Settings > Plugins` and ensure that the plugin and its dependencies (if any) are turned on.

[image: IntelliJ IDEA Plugins settings]

Comment: For anyone else that had this problem, the ctrl+shift+D and ctrl+shift+R keyboard shortcuts don't work when the JUnit plugin is disabled.